# How to project data in a particular table format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

JSON/dict data

```
data = {"outer_level_key": [{
        "random1": "",
        "url": "",
        "software": [{
            "name": "a123",
            "version": "some_version_a123"
        }],
        "memory": 72,
    },
    {
        "random1": "",
        "url": "",
        "software": [{
                "name": "a456",
                "version": "some_version_a456"
            },
            {
                "name": "a789",
                "version": "some_version_a789"
            },
            {
                "name": "b123",
                "version": "some_version_b123"
            }
        ],
        "memory": 500
    }}
```

I would like to print all the available data `name` and `version` in below format

```
++++++++++++++++++++++
name.   | version.    |
+++++++++++++++++++++++
+ a123.  |some_version_a123|
+---------------------------
+ a456.  | some_version_a456|
+----------------------------
```

Any better readability table would be better. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

(i) Traverse `data` and collect the relevant data and merge them on key using `dict.setdefault` to create `out`

(ii) Pass `out` from (i) to `DataFrame` constructor.

```
out = {}
for outer_dict in data['outer_level_key']:
    for inner_dict in outer_dict['software']:
        for k, v in inner_dict.items():
            out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Output:

```
   name            version
0  a123  some_version_a123
1  a456  some_version_a456
2  a789  some_version_a789
3  b123  some_version_b123
```

Comment: Thank you enke. this works perfeclty, I had tried this pandas approach. Anything with table design and borders (just to highlight this specific data) ?

Comment: @Learner yes you can play around with table design. You can read more about it in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```py
# main.py
print("++++++++++++++++++++++")
print("name.   | version.    |")
print("++++++++++++++++++++++")

for softwares in data["outer_level_key"]:
    for software in softwares["software"]:
        print(f"+ {software['name']}  | {software['version']}|")
        print("+---------------------------")
```

**Output:**

```
++++++++++++++++++++++
name.   | version.    |
++++++++++++++++++++++
+ a123  | some_version_a123|
+---------------------------
+ a456  | some_version_a456|
+---------------------------
+ a789  | some_version_a789|
+---------------------------
+ b123  | some_version_b123|
+---------------------------
```

Comment: That's smart :) , thank you. But adjusting table design and width many not be achieved with this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done something like this also.

```py
data_dict = {
    "outer_level_key": [
        {
            "random1": "",
            "url": "",
            "software": [{
                "name": "a123",
                "version": "some_version_a123"
            }],
            "memory": 72,
        },
        {
            "random1": "",
            "url": "",
            "software": [
                {
                    "name": "a456",
                    "version": "some_version_a456"
                },
                {
                    "name": "a789",
                    "version": "some_version_a789"
                },
                {
                    "name": "b123",
                    "version": "some_version_b123"
                }
            ],
            "memory": 500
        }]
}
print(f"{'name':<8}  | {'version':<20}")
print(f"{'-' * 9:<8} + {'-' * 20:<20}")
for software_dict in data_dict['outer_level_key']:
    for software in software_dict["software"]:
        print(f"{software['name']:<8}  | {software['version']:<20}")
```

Output:

```
name      | version             
--------- + --------------------
a123      | some_version_a123   
a456      | some_version_a456   
a789      | some_version_a789   
b123      | some_version_b123
```